# How does the angular-cli package css?

Tags: css, webpack, angular-cli

I am struggling to convert an Angular 2 project to Angular 4 using `angular-cli` and `webpack`. I am running into an issue accessing image assets from my `scss` files. I believe that my problem is being caused by the way that the directory structure of my `scss` files are being flattened. Within the `src` directory of my project I have a `stlyes` sub-directory and an `assets` sub-directory (which is a sibling of the `styles` directory). Both directories have nested child directories. My current belief in that the `assets` directory when packaged has keeps its sub-directory structure and the `styles` directory is flattened, thus causing relative references to assets from the flattened `css` to be incorrect.

For example `/src/styles/partials/_sprite.scss`:

```
.icon {
  background: url("../../assets/images/sprite-svg-ui.svg") no-repeat;
}
```

Within my IDE this reference resolves correctly, but when built by the `angular-cli` I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./~/postcss-loader?{"ident":"postcss"}!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false,"precision":8,"includePaths":[]}!./src/styles/index.scss
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../assets/images/sprite-svg-ui.svg' in 'C:\Users\jhart\Desktop\pascal.ui\src\styles'
 @ ./~/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./~/postcss-loader?{"ident":"postcss"}!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false,"precision":8,"includePaths":[]}!./src/styles/index.scss 6:43140-43188
 @ ./src/styles/index.scss
 @ multi ./src/styles/index.scss
```

Here's my `.angular-cli.json` file:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "ui"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "index.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "./styles/index.scss"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "dot.dot.dot.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "component": {},
    "serve": {
      "port": 3000
    }
  }
}
```

Here's my `index.scss` file referenced within the within the `apps\styles` element of the `.angular-cli.json` file:

```
// globals

@import 'functions';
@import 'variables';
@import 'mixins';
@import 'base';
@import 'boxer';

// partials

@import 'partials/grid';
@import 'partials/sprite';
@import 'partials/typography';
@import 'partials/buttons';
@import 'partials/forms';
@import 'partials/tables';
@import 'partials/utility';

// vendors
// @import 'vendors/chosen';

@import 'vendors/chartist/chartist';
@import 'vendors/ng2-select';

// component (declarations)

@import 'partials/wrapper';
@import 'partials/header';
@import 'partials/navigation-primary';
@import 'partials/footer';
@import 'partials/upload-meter';
@import 'partials/pagination';
@import 'partials/breadcrumb';
@import 'partials/tabs';
@import 'partials/cards';
@import 'partials/badges';
@import 'partials/flyouts';
@import 'partials/comments';
@import 'partials/tutorial';
@import 'partials/year-selector';
@import 'partials/upload-window';
@import 'partials/panels';
@import 'partials/charts';
@import 'partials/lists';
@import 'partials/collapse';
@import 'partials/tooltips';
@import 'partials/login';
@import 'partials/settings';

@import '../app/modules/core/components/notification-banner/styles';

// component (declarations)

@import 'partials/cbcr-view';

// directives

@import '../app/modules/core/directives/menu/menu';
```

**Update 1**

I have discovered that referencing the image assets via an absolute path `/app/assets/images/` allows build to resolve the image files, but now the reference to the image files within my IDE are invalid...

When running the application build with the absolute path `/app/assets/images/` I get a 404 when loading an image file...

**Update 2**

I changed the `prefix` parameter in my `.angular-cli.json` to `""` and then from my `/src/styles/partials/_sprite.scss` file I reference my image assets using an absolute path `/assets/images/`, for example:

```
.icon-close {
  background: url("/assets/images/close.svg") no-repeat;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}
```

My IDE is still unable to resolve the images files... but at least it builds and executes.

Comment: did you find a solution ?

Comment: I would consider what I have presently as a workaround - not a solution - I'm holding the question open, in hopes that someone who understands how the Angular-CLI works will actually offer an explanation that directly addresses my question (maybe there's documentation somewhere that I just haven't been able to find)

Answer (score 2):

I faced this problem and I solved it by putting the absolute path of the image depending on the location of the "index.scss" file in your case, not depending on the imported sub-sass file "_sprite.scss". This will give you an error a reference error from the IDE but it will work you won't get an error from webpack. I hope it helps.